# Have only the currently selected and displayed option in a select menu formatted in uppercase

Tags: jquery, html, select, selected

Lets say I have a select option list like this

```
<select>
<option selected>Bear</option>
<option>Tiger</option>
<option>Lion</option>
<option>Porcupine</option>
</select>
```

When the menu is 'inactive' and simply displaying the selected option, I want it to appear uppercase:

```
ie  BEAR \/
```

and when the menu is opened it should keep the options in their native format

```
Bear
Tiger
Lion
Porcupine
```

I know you can style all options to uppercase with css, but then when the menu is opened, all the options will be uppercase.

So I'm thinking jQuery.

Perhaps some replace function.

I've tried something close to this, but can't get it working:

```
$("select option:selected").text(t.replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function($1){ return $1.toUpperCase( ); }))
```

I've also attached it to a select change event.

Can someone help me pull this all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rRa7T/1/):

```
var map = {}, $firstOption = $('option:eq(0)');

$('select option').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();

    map[text.toLowerCase()] = {
        o:text,
        u:text.toUpperCase()
    }
});

$firstOption.text($firstOption.text().toUpperCase());

$('select').on('change',function() {
    var $selected = $('option:selected'),
        text = $selected.text().toLowerCase(),
        $siblings = $selected.siblings();

    $selected.text(map[text]['u']); 

    $siblings.each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

        $(this).text(map[text]['o']);
    });
});
```

What it does is store the original version of the text and the uppercase version of the text of each `option` element in a plain object.  The original and uppercase versions are accessible by the text of the object in all lowercase (just as a consistent identifier... however, you can make them accessible by whatever key you want.)

When you change the `select` element, it sets the text of the selected `option` to the uppercase version of its text, and sets its sibling elements' text to the original version of their text.

**Update**

Added a function that changed the text of the first `option` to uppercase by default when the page loads.

### Updated Code

Here is an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jruJ7/1/), that I think is a bit simpler, and in response to your comment, I have changed it to select whichever is the first option selected when the page loads:

```
var map = {}, $selected = $('option:selected');

$('select option').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();

    map[text.toLowerCase()] = {
        o:text,
        u:text.toUpperCase()
    }
});

$selected.text($selected.text().toUpperCase());

$('select').on('change',function() {
    $('option').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            text = $this.text(),
            bool = $this.is(':selected'),
            l = text.toLowerCase(),
            u = map[l]['u'],
            o = map[l]['o'],

            fn = {
                'true': function() { $this.text(u) },
                'false': function() { $this.text(o) }
            }[bool]();

     })
});
```

### Used as jQuery Plug-in

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jruJ7/6/):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.toggleSelect = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var map = {}, $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');

            $(this).find('option').each(function() {
                var text = $(this).text();

                map[text.toLowerCase()] = {
                    o:text,
                    u:text.toUpperCase()
                }
            });

            $selected.text($selected.text().toUpperCase());

            $(this).on('change',function() {
                $(this).find('option').each(function() {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        text = $this.text(),
                        bool = $this.is(':selected'),
                        l = text.toLowerCase(),
                        u = map[l]['u'],
                        o = map[l]['o'],

                        fn = {
                            'true': function() { $this.text(u) },
                            'false': function() { $this.text(o) }
                        }[bool]();

                 })
            });
        });
    }
}(jQuery));

$('#a').toggleSelect();
```

Simply select a `select` element with a jQuery selector (such as `$('a')`), and then call `toggleSelect`.  In the above code, **only the first `select` element in the jsFiddle has the method applied to it.** This method will work with multiple `select` elements.

Comment: can you update it so not just the FIRST option is uppercase to start, but whatever the selected option is on the page load?

Comment: with the second implementation. The current selected option is looking like this:  BEARBEAR

Comment: Also, I am wondering how you can implement it so it will work with multiple select menus on the same page.

Comment: What browser are you using? Edit: Nevermind, it's because you are using multiple select menus.  Give me one second, I'll give you some updated code.

Comment: Ok, so this code is working perfectly when there is just one select element on the page. ( i think that my note of BEARBEAR was due to having two selects on the page )

Comment: I've updated the code to work with multiple select elements.  Just call $('#theIDofyourselectmenu').toggleSelect().

Comment: Glad it works for you.  I just updated the code I think about 5 seconds after you posted your most recent comment, so if you decide to use it, make sure you get the updated code (it calls 'return this' at the end, which allows for chainable methods in jQuery).

Comment: Also, please close the question by choosing a correct answer so that the question is marked as answered.

Comment: Made one last edit:  I wrapped the function to make it an IIFE to prevent interference with other libraries, and I used return this.each() to allow you to use a class selector when calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this code for hint based on selected option:

```
$('select[name="Poradi\[\]"]').tooltip({
    position: {
        my: 'right center',
        at: 'left center'
    },
    content: function(){
        if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == 0 )
        {
            return 'Obrázek nebude zobrazen';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'Obrázek bude zobrazen ' + $(this).find('option:selected').val() + '. v pořadí';
        }
    }
});
```

Part

```
$(this).find('option:selected').val()
```

will call value of option I selected - and your code would be

```
$(this).find('option:selected').toUpperCase();
```

or so;

but I don't understand why to convert selected option on uppercase; I think that re-colouring of this option would be much better, mostly if original values are not written in only small caps (small letters).

I suppose that you would like to focus changing of text into uppercase on change - and then all code would be (for example):

```
$('select[name="???"]').change(
    function(){
        $(this).find('option:selected').css('color', '#CFCFCF');});
```

and

```
$('select[name="???"]').change(
    function(){
        $(this).find('option:not(:selected)').css('color', '#FFFFFF');});
```

or

```
$('select[name="???"]').change(
    function(){
        $(this).find('option:selected').css('text-transform', 'uppercase');});
```

and

```
$('select[name="???"]').change(
    function(){
        $(this).find('option:not(:selected)').css('text-transform', 'capitalize');});
```

or

```
$('select[name="???"]').change(
    function(){
        $(this).find('option:not(:selected)').css('text-transform', 'none');});
```

BTW: I am sorry for czech language of texts displayed by script written above.

As @smclark89 writes, it is possible to use also

```
$('select[name="???"]').change(
    function(){
        $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').css('text-transform', 'uppercase');});
```

and (thus for re-formatting back to original caps)

```
$('select[name="???"]').change(
    function(){
        $(this).find('option').filter(':not(:selected)').css('text-transform', 'none');});
```

**Edit**:

```
$('option:selected').each(function(){
    $(this).css('text-transform', 'uppercase' );
});
```

will set default :selected values transformed on uppercase

```
$('option:selected').change(function(){
    $(this).css('text-transform', 'uppercase' );
});
```

will transform values of selected options on uppercase - when they are selected.

But it is displayed only when options are displayed, not else.

**Edit**:
Beware: Probably it will be correct only in some browsers. I found that Opera does not like formatting of elements inside of `<select>`, when I finished my supertemplate machine and did tests of it. You would find that chosen element has got new style in code, but it will be not displayed.

Comment: Good answer, and it can all fit into a one-liner: $('select[name="???"]').change(
    function(){
        $(this).find('option').css('text-transform', 'none').filter(':selected').css('text-transform', 'uppercase');});

Comment: @smclark89: I used ??? because value of name of select form is not known. I rather use ('option:selected') but your version may be a little more comfortable for reading, mostly due to secondary selector :not(':selected').

Comment: The intention of my comment was to illustrate that both logical operations (make selected item uppercase, make all other items lowercase) could be written in a single line. I like elegance :)

Comment: I'm trouble getting it to work still. It should also do the transform on the load of the page, so the option before the change event is uppercase.

Comment: @DillHoffman: So, use $(document).ready() and function for getting default statement place into brackets of .ready(). If uppercase is default option (loaded from any source, like DB), use .filter(':not(:selected)').css('text-transform', 'lowercase'); if it is not default, use .filter(':selected').css('text-transform', 'uppercase')

Comment: have you tested the solution? What would be the final code that could be used for this, based on everything you've posted?

Comment: Tested - and in bottom of answer you have code that will do that (transform selected options on uppercase). But (at least in FF) you will see it only after _opening_ of select form, as I found. So, all you need to do, is adding of code that reverts change.